# Hiding a menu item in MFC

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, menu

How can I hide a menu item under certain conditions in MFC? 
I'm not interested in just graying it out.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Add an Update Handler for your menu item (using ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI).

This line should appear in your message map:

```
  ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI(ID_MYMENUITEM, OnUpdateMyMenuItem)
```

In the handler, use this code:

```
void CMainFrame::OnUpdateMyMenuItem(CCmdUI *pCmdUI)
{
  if (pCmdUI->m_pMenu!=NULL)
    pCmdUI->m_pMenu->DeleteMenu(pCmdUI->m_nID, MF_BYCOMMAND);
}
```

Comment: Was having trouble getting a valid pointer to the correct CMenu object - this code did the trick!

Answer (score 3):

Or if you are removing a single menu item use CMenu::[RemoveMenu](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms647994%28VS.85%29.aspx)